# How to upgrade the :update=>'div_id' option of remote_form_for from Rails 2 to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade, form-for

I can't figure out how to upgrade this code from Rails 2 to Rails 3:

```
<% remote_form_for(item, :update => 'div_id') do |f| %>
...
```

I tried this:

```
<%= form_for :item, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "items", :action => "create" }, :update => 'div_id' do |f| %>
...
```

It creates the new item but **it fails in updating the content** within `<div id="div_id"></div>` tags. It seems Rails 3 no longer supports the "`:update`" option for a remote `form_for`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use RJS, but that's being deprecated too (and for good reason). The simplified, best-practices way to handle this in Rails 3+ is as follows (assuming jQuery):

```
# your_view.html.erb
<div id="receiver-id"></div>

<%= form_for :some_model, :remote => true, :id => 'form-id' do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>


# application.js (or any other .js loaded on the page)
$(function(){
  $('#form-id').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $('#receiver-id').html(data);
  });
});
```

The `ajax:success` hook gets called by the jquery-ujs (aka jquery-rails, aka rails-ujs) remote link/form handler. [See for yourself.](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js) There are lots of other callbacks/hooks available for you to use, too. If you wanted to make this even more flexible, you could use `live` instead of `bind`, and bind to a class that dictates where the ouput goes (e.g. "sidebar") and then all remote links/forms with the `sidebar` class would have their HTML response go to `div#sidebar`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but maybe I'm too rookie for this (I started studying RoR few months ago) so I can't make your solution work. I guess I need to use "live" instead of "bind" as I need to update the content of a div (id="div_id" in the example) on form submission (not necessarily to the successful creation of the new item). May somebody please write down a solution assuming this is the first time I need to use jQuery? Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial instead. Go do a jQuery tutorial, an unobtrusive javascript tutorial for Rails, and another for remote/ajax rails requests. Then it'll all make sense.

Comment: Ok, I'll surely follow your suggestion as jQuery is absolutely in my to-study list. I was only hoping to solve this very problem in a short time...

Comment: One issue @Duccio probably ran into was Javascript driver incompatibility.  coreyward's solution assumes that the Rails javascript driver is jQuery.  Rails 3.0 installs the Prototype javascript driver by default.  This is problematic when you try to define hooks using jQuery.

Comment: FYI - The Javascript in this example is missing a final );

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to write a javascript view template, e.g. `create.js.erb` which would look something like this:

```
$('#div_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@item)) %>");
```

(depending on your setup, of course, I'm assuming an `@item` variable and an associated `_item` partial)

Edit:
coreyward is right.  This is the RJS way which is more of the old fashioned Rails 2.x "Rails way".  It's probably more familiar, but has issues.  Your specific case is one of them, actually, as typically you might bind to an HTML element to update using the record's `id` (e.g. div #item_1), and in the `create` case there is no `id` available beforehand, complicating matters.

Binding via clientside JS eliminates this issue.  RJS works in something of a vacuum, making assumptions about the state of the client's HTML and having no access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but I when migrating to Rails 3 I found a pretty good way of doing this, so I thought I would post it here in case anyone else is in a similar solution.

In layouts/update_page.js.erb I put this file:

```
$j('#<%=@update_div_id||"list_div"%>').html('<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => (@partial_div||"index"), :locals => @local_hash) %>');
```

This is mainly used for searches that use remote, so in the index action in the controller, I just added the following code.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js {render 'layouts/update_page'}
end
```

Since remote is being used, it will always try to use javascript first, so it will render the update_page.js.erb file from above.  For us, we almost always use the div#list_div on our index pages, so we update that by the default, however if you need to update something different, you can pass in @update_div_id, and if you need to render a different page, you can pass in @partial_div.

To clarify, for a lot of things, it is probably better practice to use the callbacks, but I found this to be a much easier way, when we had to migrate over nearly 100 of these calls.